# Unable to see files in DVD hidden using windows 7

Tags: nautilus, 13.10, dvd, filemanager, hidden-files

I had hidden folders using Windows 7 and burned them to a DVD. When I checked the disk in Windows it showed all the folders (using 'show hidden files and folders'). But after performing a clean install of Ubuntu 13.10 over Windows I cannot see the hidden folders using nautilus(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> does NOT help) or any terminal commands. I badly need the data as it is important.

Presently I do not have access to a windows PC.

Comment: `any terminal commands`. which ones?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Article](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Edgy#How_to_mount.2Funmount_CD.2FDVD-ROM_manually.2C_and_show_all_hidden_and_associated_files.2Ffolders), mounting the CD/DVD wit the `unhide` option should help:

```
sudo mount /media/cdrom0/ -o unhide
```

(check the device name  of your CD/DVD device first)

Comment: terminal shows mount: can't find /media/cdrom/ in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Comment: Try to use /dev/cdrom. And you have to specify a mount point, as Ubuntu doesn't put the CD/DVD drive into /etc/fstab.